# GO, package "strings" func TrimSuffix no borra salto de linea

Tags: string, go, packages

hace poco empecé a aprender go y trato de quitar un salto de linea que hay con el package strings. Este salto de linea es el que en teoría no me permite validar el case si escribo "a" en el fmt.Print.
En la linea 42 es donde en teoría le digo que remueva ese salto de linea con la función TrimSuffix, pero al mostrar el valor de "option" sigue ahí. ayuda :(    pd: lamento si es un error muy básico :(

```
package main

import "os"
import "fmt"
import "bufio"
import "strings"

func crearUsuario(){ 
 fmt.Println ("Usuario creado exitosamente")
}
func listarUsuario(){
 fmt.Println ("Usuario Enlistado")
}
func actualizarUsuario(){
 fmt.Println ("Usuario Actualizado")
}
func eliminarUsuario(){
 fmt.Println ("Usuario Eliminado")
}

func main(){

  var reader *bufio.Reader
  var option string 

   reader = bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

  fmt.Println("A) Crear")
  fmt.Println("B) Listar")
  fmt.Println("C) Actualizar")
  fmt.Println("D) Eliminar")

  fmt.Print("Ingresa una opción valida: ")
   option, err := reader.ReadString('\n')

   if err != nil {
     panic("Fallo en el programa, imposible obtener el valor")
   }

  fmt.Println(option)
  
   option = strings.TrimSuffix(option, "\n")

  switch option {
    case "a", "crear":
      crearUsuario()
    case "b", "listar":
      listarUsuario()
    case "c", "actualizar":
      actualizarUsuario()
    case "d", "eliminar":
      eliminarUsuario()
    default:
      fmt.Println("Opción NO valida krnal")
  }
  
}
``
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

me respondo a mi mismo porque encontré la respuesta ;) "resulta" que para go 1.16.4 (versión que uso) se usa otra func distinta que es *TrimSpace* (para este caso) ya que esta literalmente borra los espacios en blanco iniciales y finales. (supongo que no era un salto en linea :p)